# Observable windowed groupBy leads to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to figure out how to use Observable.groupBy to limit the number of elements pushed by key over a time frame. I end up with the following construct:

```java
create(emitter -> {
            while (true) {
                publishedMeter.mark();
                emitter.onNext(new Object());
            }
        })
        .window(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(window -> window.groupBy(o -> o.hashCode() % 10_000).flatMapMaybe(Observable::lastElement))
        .subscribe(e -> receivedMeter.mark());
```

While subscribe's onNext callback is called a few thousand times, which I think should mean that flatMapMaybe does properly subscribe to all GroupedObservableSource. After a short while one of the thread inside RxComputationThreadPool but I don't understand what I'm missing

Comment: Have you tried `sample` or `throttleLast`? You currently split the stream into 1 second long windows of which you want the last, right?

Comment: `sample` or `throttleLast` don't quite fit the bill, as they do not allow control on how each window's grouped are folded. In the example I use `lastElement` but I may need to use `reduce` instead later on. The idea is to limit the rate of events on each group, by combining their elements over a time window. I also tried grouping, then "windowing" but had no success with that approach either.